# How to count a $link posted by a $nick in $chat more than 2 times?

Tags: php, count, explode

I'm trying to do a count of a `$link` posted in `$chat` by a `$nick` more than 2 times or more or equal of 3 times to then call for a function of ban.

I've tried `if (count(explode($link, $chat, $nick))>=3) {` which i know is not true but i'm out of options and i'm still at the beginning of PHP learning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain what your string $chat looks like? and where $nick is found? It's difficult to provide much feedback.

Comment: //Get Chat

  preg_match('%</b>:(.*)</td></tr>%U', $mess, $chat);

  $chat = $chat[1];

Comment: @BjarkeH.Søndergaard if you can at least give the the right way of calculating the count of post by a nick in a chat i will give it a try by my self :)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what your $chat string looks like entirely I will go with what would seem like a plausible solution:

```
$lines = explode("\n\r", $chat);
$links = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $nickAndLink = explode(':', $line) // assumes each line is made as "nick: text"
    $nick = $nickAndLink[0];
    $link = $nickAndLink[1];
    $link = trim($link) //Trim spaces and other spacing characters;
    if (!isset($links[$nick][$link])) {
        $links[$nick][$link] = 1;
    } else {
        $links[$nick][$link] += 1;
    }
    if ($links[$nick][$link] >= 3) {
        echo $nick . " is spamming";
    }
}
```

This is not terribly efficient, but is the only thing I can come up with given the information I have. Hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: i'm not sure how to explain it, you can see the script live in http://aseanlegacy.net 
thanks again